# Logic is working fine in C++ but when same logic is Implemented in Javascript code leads to runtime error, why?

Tags: javascript, c++

Input: Unordered consecutive integer array e.g. [6,4,3,1,2,5]
Output: Minimum number of swaps required to sort the array in ascending order [1,2,3,4,5,6]

For the same purpose the **C++ implementation** is:

```
int minimumSwaps(vector<int> arr) {

int i,c=0,n=arr.size();
for(i=0;i<n;i++)
{
    if(arr[i]==(i+1))
        continue;
    
    swap(arr[i],arr[arr[i]-1]);
    c++;
    i--;
}
return c;

}
```

**The C++ code is working fine!!**

But when the same logic is implemented in JavaScript it is going into endless loop leading to runtime error.

**JavaScript implementation:**

```
function minimumSwaps(arr) {
  let swaps=0,n=arr.length,i=0;

  for(i=0; i<n; i++){
      if(arr[i]===(i+1))
          continue;
        
    
      let temp= arr[i];
      arr[i]= arr[arr[i]-1];
      arr[arr[i]-1]=temp;
      swaps++;
      i--;
   }   

   return swaps;
 }
```

**How to solve this issue and make the JavaScript code working?**

Comment: Did you try debugging your js code using console logs? Direct translation of code may fail due to nuances in the language itself. Also can you specify what is the runtime error you are seeing?

Comment: because you have `i--`. when the loop runs `i` is equal to `0` and then it become `-1` from `i--` then when it starts again, `i++` runs and it becomes `0` again, so `i < n` is always true, which is why it's stuck in a loop

Answer (score 0):

```js
function minimumSwaps(arr) {
    let swaps = 0, n = arr.length, i = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        if (arr[i] === (i + 1)) {
            let temp = arr[i];
            arr[i] = arr[arr[i] - 1];
            arr[arr[i] - 1] = temp;
            swaps++;
        }
    }
    return swaps;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Issue with swaping value between array's index. in c++ you used a method but in js you tried to write manually, but your written code is **wrong**

 
Instead use this code, it is optimized

```
function minimumSwaps(arr) {
    let swaps=0,n=arr.length,j=0;
    for(var i=0; i<n; i=j){
        if(arr[i]!=(i+1)){
            var temp = arr[i];
            arr[i] = arr[temp-1];
            arr[temp-1] = temp;
            swaps++;
        }else j++;
     }
    return swaps;
}
```

Or simply optimize your code

```
for(i=0; i<n; i++){
  if(arr[i]===(i+1))
      continue;
    
    let temp= arr[i]; //temp is 6 as per your list
    arr[i]= arr[arr[i]-1]; //just now you changed arr[i] into arr[arr[i]-1] , so it will become 5 as per your list,
    arr[temp-1]=temp; //now temp-1 is 5 but if you use arr[arr[i]-1] it will become 4 bcoz arr[i] is 5 now
    swaps++;
    i--;
   }
```

in your code the issue was,
first you set `temp` to `arr[i]` and `arr[i]` to `arr[arr[i]-1]`

so next time when you call `arr[arr[i]-1]`  it become *arr[**arr[arr[i]-1**]-1* as you previously set arr[i] as arr[arr[i]-1]